# Escaping - character when reading from Java properites

Tags: java, character-encoding, escaping, properties-file

I'm trying to read in a - value from a Java properties file, but it keeps giving me the value â and something like an epsilon (having issues pasting it)

I have no issues escaping the " but it seems like no matter what I do - is giving me issues. I've tried '-' and \- and \\- but nothing seems to be working.

```
@Test
public void readFromProperties() throws IOException {
    Properties options = new Properties();

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(Configs.optionsFi);
    negComments.load(in);
    in.close();

    String option = options.getProperty("OPTION8");
    System.out.println(negComment);
}
```

properties file:

```
OPTION8=asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf – \"asdfasdf\"
```

System.out.println result:

```
asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf âepsilonlikething "asdfasdf"
```

Comment: in your example you have `option` equal to the good string value but the system.out.println is a weird result. However what you are printing in system isn't `option` but something called `negComment`. Why is that? where is it defined\created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `–` character in the property file is not a normal dash (['HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002D/index.htm)), but an ['EN DASH' (U+2013)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

Documentation of [`load(InputStream inStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-) explicitly specifies:

> The input stream is in a simple line-oriented format as specified in load(Reader) and is assumed to use the **ISO 8859-1** character encoding; that is each byte is one Latin1 character.

Your property file is in UTF-8, so you get that character encoding error.

There are 3 ways to fix the problem:

1. Assuming that you intended a normal dash, replace the `–` with a `-`,
   and make sure you save the file in ISO 8859-1 aka Latin1 aka Windows-1252.
2. Encode the character, i.e. replace `–` with `\u2013`,
   and make sure you save the file in ISO 8859-1 aka Latin1 aka Windows-1252.
3. Read the file using UTF-8:

   ```
   try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(Configs.optionsFi))) {
       options.load(in);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Encodings just drive me crazy. Option 3 worked as expected.